# Pandas .apply with conditional if in different columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe as below. I am trying to check if there is a `nan` in the `Liq_Factor`, if yes, put 1 otherwise divide `use/TW`. Result in column Testing.

```
+---+------------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1 |            | Liq_Factor | Zscire | Use    | Tw     |
| 2 | 01/10/2020 | 36.5       | 44     | 43.875 | 11.625 |
| 3 | 02/10/2020 | Nan        | 43.625 | 13.625 | 33.25  |
| 4 | 03/10/2020 | 6.125      | 47.875 | 22.5   | 4.625  |
| 5 | 04/10/2020 | Nan        | 34.25  | 37.125 | 36     |
| 6 | 05/10/2020 | 43.875     | 17.375 | 5.5    | 36.25  |
| 7 | 06/10/2020 | 40         | 14.125 | 21.125 | 14.875 |
| 8 | 07/10/2020 | 42.25      | 44.75  | 21.25  | 31.75  |
+---+------------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I was wondering if i can use `.apply` in the sense of

```
DF1['Testing']=(DF1['Liq_Factor'].apply(lambda x: x=1 if pd.isna(DF1['Zscore']) else DF1['Use']/DF1['Tw'])
```

Can you please help?

Thanks,
H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code-

```
df['Testing']=df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['Liq_Factor']=='Nan'  else x['Use']/x['Tw'], axis=1)
```

Based on changes in comment section

```
df['Testing']=df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['Liq_Factor']=='Nan'  else min(x['Use']/x['Tw'],1), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use apply or another alternative is where function from numpy:

```
df['Liq_Factor'] = np.where(df['Liq_Factor'] == np.Nan, 1, df['Use']/df['TW'])
```

Following your comments below you can do:

```
# create another column with the calculation
df['calc'] = (1/3)* df['ATV']/df['TW']*100000000
# create two rules (you can use one rule and then the opposite)
mask_0 = (df['calc'] < 1)
mask_1 = (df['calc'] > 1)
# change result value by condition
df.loc[mask_0, 'Liq Factor'] = df['calc']
df.loc[mask_1, 'Liq Factor'] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works but i have two questions please.
1. Is there a way to do it with pandas?
2. If yes, What if i have more than one condition? Can this be done in pandas?

Comment: For your first question posted the answer using pandas, for second question you can create a function with your input columns and calculation logic with many conditions, call that function using apply.

Comment: When I added the "min" I get the below error

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

My line code is as below
```Final['Liq Factor'] = np.where(Final['ATV'] == np.nan, 1, min((1/3)*(Final['ATV']/Final['TW']*1000000000),1))```

Any help please?

Comment: @Hassanov -  What are you trying to do? What is the min used for?

Comment: If is nan, put 1 otherwise, get the minimum between (1/3)* ATV/TW*100000000) and 1

Comment: I also tried to write a function as Sushant suggested (and added an extra layer of it) but i get the same error. ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```def Liq_F(DF1):
    DF1['Liq_Factor']=1
    for i in range(len(DF1)):
        if DF1['ATV'].iloc[i]== 'Nan':
            DF1['Liq_Factor'].iloc[i]=1
        elif DF1['TW'].iloc[i]==0:
            DF1['Liq_Factor'].iloc[i]=0
        else:
            min((1/3)*(Final['ATV']/Final['TW']*1000000000),1)

Liq_F(Final)``` Can you please help me identify the error?

Comment: You can not do it like this, because df['ATV'] for example, is not a single number but a whole column. Let me write a solution for you. A few minutes please

Comment: @Hassanov - see above.

Comment: @Hassanov use min(a,b) to get the minimum, its working fine for me- I have updated it in my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I understand now it why my line of code doesnt work and both solution offered by you works! Many thanks again :)